# Login with username, but login with lowercase username

Tags: php, sql, authentication, lowercase

I have recently had alot of suggestions on my website, and one of them was to allow them to login with their username in lowercase.

If JoHNdoE had their username like that in the database, I'm sure it would get quite annoying if they tried to login and having to remember where they put those capitals.

So I wanted to make it so they John Doe could login with this username johndoe instead. MUCH MUCH easier to remember.

my query is currently

```
$get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$entered_username' AND md5_username = '$md5_entered_username' AND password = '$entered_password' LIMIT 1");
```

And then it will continue with

```
if (mysql_num_rows($get_user_info)==1) {
//then log them in
} else {
//kick 'em out!
}
```

How would I go about this?

Comment: Why do you store and compare the md5 hash of the username? Why do you not store a hash of the password? That makes no sense!

Comment: I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: Whoa, you are wide open for a SQL injection. Check out the SO thread on [the best way to stop SQL injections in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: you should be using PreparedStatements instead of the generic queries if you'd want to prevent SQL Injection attacks. During which you could easily process the input and convert the input string into lowercase in php... Of course you'd have to store the username all in lowercase in the db to beginwith

Comment: Before loosening your login rules, make sure you don't have users who differ in username only by case.

Comment: 3 comments on security after I started my comment.. lulz

Comment: I have, the variables $entered_username, $entered_password etc are all ran through mysql_real_escape() and then strip_tags(). Is this good enough?

Comment: The database doesn't care at all about tags. You should be stripping tags on the path database -> client on the fields where it makes sense. What do you care if a user signs up with account name `<blink>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you format the username so that it eliminates SQL injection attacks
2. Md5 hash for username would be pointless as uppercase and lower case matters. You should be hashing the password instead and not be storing that in plain text
3. But, based on your current DB model

   ```
   $get_user_info = mysql_query(
       "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$entered_username'  LIMIT 1")
   ```

   now compare the password. You can't use the Md5's username

Comment: Thanks for actually answering the question rather than wondering about my security too much.

Comment: Np, but security matters. Many large sites have been taken down by SQL Injection attacks. One general rule is to ALWAYS filter input from the user

Comment: I ALWAYS do that. Any variable that holds or contains user created data is ran through mysql_real_escape_string() and is then filtered for html with strip_tags() Is this good enough?

Comment: @Frank - Yep, using them both will be fine

Comment: Thanks, What is all this about then? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: But that variable "$var" is not established on the page?

Comment: That would be the better approach as it makes it easier for the developer not to make a mistake. Using what you're doing, you've got to manually clean/format every string, whereas the prepared statements will do it for you. In the end, you'll end up with the same result.

Comment: Well I've already started the manual filtering, so I may aswell finish it.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from all the comments I agree with about security (especially the password hashing...), to make the username case insensitive:

```
$entered_username = strtolower($entered_username);
$get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE LOWER(`username`) = '$entered_username' AND `password` = '$entered_password' LIMIT 1");
```

If your usernames are unique (I assume they are...), you can remove the `LIMIT` clause and you can also remove the password check and do that in php so that you are better able to handle login errors (separate non-existing username from wrong password).